# Export Django logs to Azure AppInsights with OpenCensus

Tags: django, azure-application-insights, opencensus

I'm following this guidance for [Django](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/tree/master/contrib/opencensus-ext-django) and [Azure](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/tree/master/contrib/opencensus-ext-azure).  I'm able to get dependancies and requests, but not traces.

I added this to middleware:

'opencensus.ext.django.middleware.OpencensusMiddleware'

Here is the LOGGING and OPENCENSUS portions of settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'default': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(processName)s - %(name)s\n%(message)s',
    },
},
"handlers": {
    "azure": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
    "class": "opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter.AzureLogHandler",
        "instrumentation_key": assert_env('APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'),
     },
    "console": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        "formatter": "default",
     },
  },
"loggers": {
    "logger_name": {"handlers": ["azure", "console"]},
},
    # For some reason, this is needed or logging doesn't show up in the
    # celery log file.
'skyforge.tasks': {
    'handlers': ['azure','console'],
    'level': assert_env('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL'),
},
```

}

```
OPENCENSUS = {
    'TRACE': {
        'SAMPLER': 'opencensus.trace.samplers.ProbabilitySampler(rate=1)',
        'EXPORTER': '''opencensus.ext.azure.trace_exporter.AzureExporter(
            service_name='skyforge'
        )'''
        #Assumes Environmental Variable 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
    }
}
```

Any guidance on where to look for why no trace logs.  The django-critical and django-tasks are still going to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the part that is wrong:

```
"loggers": {
"logger_name": {"handlers": ["azure", "console"]},
```

The `"logger_name"` needed to be populated with the App name so that
`logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` worked properly.

Also a level is needed in the logger.

Here is what worked for me.

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'default': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(processName)s - %(name)s\n%(message)s',
    },
},
'handlers': {
     'azure': {
        'class': 'opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter.AzureLogHandler',
        'formatter':'default'
        # https://pypi.org/project/opencensus-ext-azure/
        #Assumed ENV APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING
      },
    'console': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'default',

    },
  },
'loggers': {
    'polls': {
        'handlers': ['azure', 'console'],
        'level':'DEBUG'
        },
}
```

}

The following options did not make a difference:
`'level'` parameter in handler
`'filter':'[]'` in handler
`'stream':sys.stdout` in handler.

I put the Appinsights connection string in an environmental variable, but the reference shows how to place in settings also. Also the original key in settings seems to work also.

```
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING=InstrumentaionKey=<key uuid>
```